# FoxPro to WPF porting help?

Tags: wpf, foxpro

I am porting an application based on foxpro to WPF C# but i stuck in this window & i need your help.

here is a screen shot of window [Click Here](http://picasaweb.google.com/raj.kishor09/RAJK?feat=directlink).

this is basically a wine shop billing part which allows to bill upto 99 items. Code col. allows to input item code and all description will come up. I am looking for something similar interface in WPF.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything out of the box, but create a tabular window, and to each row add a textbox that will load all descriptions after its text is changed. You'd have to calculate subtotal and total stuff by yourself, but clever use of databound controls and LINQ would allow you to create this kind of interface elegantly.

Comment: You can find a LINQ to VFP dll at http://linqtovfp.codeplex.com if you choose to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of developers in Europe (Uwe Habermann and Venelina Jordanova) who are working on a Visual FoxPro to Silverlight product right now. They are presenting it in Europe during the summer of 2010 and at the Southwest Fox Conference held in Mesa, AZ, USA this October. It is a free pre-conference session if you subscribe to their framework, subscribe to FoxRockX, or attend the conference.

(full disclosure, I am one of the organizers of Southwest Fox Conference, but hopefully it does not make the information any less valuable).

Rick Schummer, VFP MVP